# Синтаксическая ошибка SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Есть таблица в базе. Пытаюсь вывести ее на страницу таким образом:

```
$link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $db_name);
mysqli_query($link, "SET NAMES 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci'");
mysqli_query($link, "SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");
mysqli_set_charset($link,'utf8');
$table = 'states'; //задаем имя таблицы в переменной
$result =mysqli_query($link, "SELECT*FROM ".$table." WHERE id>0") or die(mysqli_error($link));
$table = "<table border=2>";
$table.=" <thead>
<th>ФИО</th>
<th>Должность</th>
<th>Образование</th>
<th>Стаж, лет</th>
<th>Оклад</th>
</thead>";
$rows = mysqli_num_rows($result); // количество полученных строк

    for ($i = 0 ; $i < $rows ; ++$i)
    {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
        $table .= "<tr>";
            for ($j = 1 ; $j < 6 ; ++$j) $table.="<td>$row[$j]</td>";
        $table .= "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";

    // очищаем результат
    mysqli_free_result($result);


$table .= "</table> ";
echo $table;
```

Выдает такую ошибку:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '' at line 1

Ковыряюсь уже кучу времени не могу добиться вывода.

Comment: Выведите запрос на экран и попробуйте ввести его в консоли mysql или phpmyadmin. Также можно удалить все строки кроме первой и выполнить, потом добавлять по строкам и смотреть где ошибка.

Comment: `SELECT*FROM` пробелы не нужны?

Answer (score 0):

если используете двойные кавычки, то можно так:

```
mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE id > 0") or die(mysqli_error($link));
```

Comment: Спасибо так заработало!

Comment: и правда, давайте в случае ошибки всем пользователям вываливать сообщение и текст запроса. пусть посмотрят, как инъекцию проще сделать.

Comment: Что за таблица где поле id может быть отрицательным?

Comment: @u_mulder А почему нет? В андроид SQLite это не сложно сделать если не ставить поле id как автоинкрементируемое, а самому сделать итератор.